# Where does this road lead to?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am new in a new city and I am not familiar with this city. Sometimes I want to ask a friend or just a stranger for the correct direction. Usually I would ask "where does this road lead to" when I was wondering the destination of a road or what is another road connect with this road.

So is "Where does this road lead to?" a right way to ask?

Comment: It's at least as common (probably *more* common) to use ***go*** rather than ***lead*** in such contexts. And although it's not easy to prove my point with corpus searches, I'd be pretty sure that ***as a spoken usage***, most native speakers wouldn't include that final preposition ***to***. So the most common form would simply be ***Where does this road go**?*

Comment: (At least that would avoid the smartass reply *"Same as [all roads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_roads_lead_to_Rome) - it **leads to Rome**!"* :)

Comment: Although you did not ask, in the US you would usually ask about a "street" rather than a "road" in the context of an urban setting.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing is not incorrect, but I think as a query for directions it's a little vague. The person you're asking does not know what you're after -- are you trying to get to a specific location, or asking if this street/road goes to a general area, or just trying to get some general information on where it goes without a specific goal of your own in mind?

So you could say "Can I get to X by going on this road?", or "Will this road get me to X?" (or "...lead me to X?").

As to street or road (as brought up in a comment), in the US we tend to regard a 'street' as a paved roadway that is in a city or town, could be a "downtown area" with lots of streets and buildings, or could be a suburban area with lots of residence driveways on the street. 'Road' usually means a paved roadway that is going to continue for a longer distance. But this isn't a strong distinction, the terms are used pretty much interchangably and will certainly both be understood.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand it! I was just trying to get some general information on where it goes without a specific goal of my own in mind.